# Targeting many platforms with many dependencies using VS2015 + hg

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, version-control, dependencies, mercurial-subrepos

I have a c++ project, with source managed using hg mercurial.

I am porting it to support android, iOS and linux.
I am using the cross-platform capabilities of Visual Studio 2015 to do this.

The problem is that for windows debug/release x32/x64 alone I would have to compile 56 dependency dlls. This alone is not a problem, but setting up everything for everyone who wants to contribute would be cumbersome.

Because of this I am trying to include the source and build of all dependencies to be compiled for the given platform when necessary.

Now some of these sources are from github, some from mercurial. Is there any way I can effectively keep the dependencies as repositories, while being inside my main project repository?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note: "some of these sources are from github, some from mercurial" == "some are man, some are nice". GitHub is platform, Mercurial is SCM - it is not logically correct counterpose them in this way

*If* you want to collect all dependencies in one repo, you can think about (if you prefer pure Mercurial-way) [subrepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) (subrepos can be local or remote, non-Mercurial subrepos /Git with hg-git/ also supported).

PS: read and grok [Alternatives](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository#Alternatives) section on Subrepo wiki page carefully

Comment: Thanks for the correction and info. I decided to just add the library directories to my ignore and add a script to get them to respective directories automagically.